# Let $n$ and $m$ be integers such that $5$ divides $1+2n^2+3m^2.$ Then show that $5$ divides $n^2-1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ and $m$ be integers such that $5$ divides $1+2n^2+3m^2.$ Then show that $5$ divides $n^2-1.$

$\textbf{My attempts} :$

From the condition, we can write $$1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 0(\mod 5)\tag 1$$
Now, since $5$ is prime so by Fermat's little theorem, we can write $$n^4\equiv 1(\mod 5)\quad\text{and} \quad m^4\equiv 1(\mod 5).$$
So, we get $n^4-m^4\equiv 0(\mod 5)$.
Since $5$ prime so, either $5|(m^2+n^2)$ or $5|(m^2-n^2).$
Now if $5|(m^2+n^2)$ then from $(1)$ we get $$1-n^2+3n^2+3m^2\equiv 0(\mod 5)$$ So, we are done.

Now, if $5|(m^2-n^2)$ then from $(1)$ we get $$1+5n^2-3n^2+3m^2\equiv 0(\mod 5).$$ So, we shall arrive at a contradiction that $1\equiv 0(\mod 5).$

In this way, I have tried to solve this problem. I will be highly obliged if you kindly check this or correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please change the tag to elementary-number-theory

Comment: I do not see any problem to your solution so far. Maybe you could say in front that $n^2$ and $m^2$ may not have the same value modulo 5, because of the mentioned contradiction. Everything else is nice, and more elegant than the solutions down, since you would need to go over some cases..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squares are $0,1,4 \pmod 5$   so $3m^2 \equiv 0,3,2 \pmod 5,$ next $1+3m^2 \equiv 1,4,3 \pmod 5$ Finally
$$ -(1+3m^2)  \equiv 4,1,2 \pmod 5 \; , \; \;  $$
$$  2 n^2 \equiv 0,2,3 \pmod 5 $$

The overlap of these two lists, $4,1,2$  and $0,2,3$  is the single possibility $2.$  That is, we need $2n^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ and $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit easier. The cool thing working $\mod 5$ is that squares are always $\equiv 0$ or $\equiv \pm 1$ (you see this by just entering all possibilities). If you know that
$$
1+2n^2+3m^2 \equiv 0 \mod 5
$$
test out the possibilities of $n,m \mod 5$ to see what works:
\begin{align}
n^2\equiv 0, m^2\equiv 0 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 1 \not\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv 1, m^2\equiv 0 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 3 \not\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv -1, m^2\equiv 0 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv -1 \not\equiv 0 \\ \\
n^2\equiv 0, m^2\equiv 1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 4 \not\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv 1, m^2\equiv 1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 6 \not\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv -1, m^2\equiv 1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 2 \not\equiv 0 \\ \\
n^2\equiv 0, m^2\equiv -1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv -2 \not\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv 1, m^2\equiv -1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 0 \\
n^2\equiv -1, m^2\equiv -1 \Rightarrow 1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv -4\not\equiv 0 \\
\end{align}

By the table above you (you could also get this by systematic thinking without trying out all possibilities), you see that $n^2\equiv 1$ which means that $n^2-1\equiv 0 \mod 5$, so $n^2-1$ is divisible by $5$ if $1+2n^2+3m^2$ is (and in that case you also know that $m^2+1$ is divisible by $5$ as well)

Comment: Thank you. Very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If $1+2n^2+3m^2\equiv 0\pmod 5$, then $n^2\equiv m^2+2$.
Since the only squares modulo $5$ are $0,\pm 1$, the only values for $n^2$ and $m^2$ are $n^2\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $m^2\equiv -1\pmod 5$.